# CZMQ actors allow only one publish & one subscribe

Tags: zeromq

I am testing the UDP beacon functions in CZMQ and it seems that once an actor is created; it only allows one subscribe and one publish.

Is this correct (which would mean that if I want to send more data, I would need to create multiple actors)? Or is it possible to subscribe and publish multiple messages with the same actor?